IOS transceive NFCTagType.iso7816
I'm using the following code to read NFC tags as card IDs on iOS:
if (tag.type == NFCTagType.iso7816) {
  String result1 = await FlutterNfcKit.transceive("00a40400");
  setState(() {
    _result = '1: $result1\n';
  });
}

And I am encountering an error:
[CoreNFC] -[NFCTagReaderSession setAlertMessage:]:101 (null)
[CoreNFC] -[NFCTagReaderSession transceive:tagUpdate:error:]:883 Error Domain=NFCError Code=2 "Missing required entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required entitlement}

I have added the following to the info.plist file:
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
<array>
  <string>12FC</string>
  <string>6A82</string>
  <string>8008</string>
</array>
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
<array>
  <string>A0000002471001</string>
  <string>A0000002472001</string>
  <string>A000000151000000</string>
  <string>A00000000386980701</string>
  <string>A000000003101001</string>
  <string>A000000003101002</string>
  <string>A0000000041010</string>
  <string>A0000000042010</string>
  <string>A0000000044010</string>
  <string>44464D46412E44466172653234313031</string>
  <string>D2760000850100</string>
  <string>D2760000850101</string>
  <string>00000000000000</string>
</array>

And the Runner.entitlements file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
  <array>
    <string>TAG</string>
    <string>NDEF</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>


I'll explain WELL how the command you're sending works once and for all!
FlutterNfcKit.transceive("00a40400");


1th Byte : instructionClass CLA == '00'
2th Byte : instructionCode  INS == 'a4'*
3th Byte : p1Parameter      P1  == '04'*
4th Byte : p2Parameter      P2  == '00'
5th Byte : Data Byte count  CL  == '00'
6.. Bytes: Data

(*) In javacard A4 0A is the command to select an applet on the card, You didn't post which applet!! obviously it doesn't work
the CL parameter which is the Byte count is mandatory, if you don't have to pass any bytes, you will however pass '00' otherwise it doesn't work. But as I wrote to you a few lines before, the AID or the HEX identifier of the applet you are selecting on the card is missing
An example :
00 A4 04 00 09 D1 56 00 01 32 83 26 01 01
in bold you'll notice that I'm selecting an applet from the '0xA4,0x04' card.
In italics the applet id [exactly the one that goes in the IOS entitlement
09 : it's the byte count I'm sending to the card
